# The directory is not writable by the Web process: /var/www/html/mywebsite/frontend/web/assets

Tags: apache, yii2

I'm trying to initialize Yii2 apps and after i run the command php init and all files generated by yii i try to view from n=my browser but keep getting error, i have search on google and on stackflow for possible solution with no luck, what i've tried so far, i run the command  `chmod 0777 web/assets` i also do `ps -ef | grep apache | grep -v grep` and i got the below

```
apache     4074   4073  0 20:38 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache     4075   4073  0 20:38 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache     4076   4073  0 20:38 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache     4077   4073  0 20:38 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache     4078   4073  0 20:38 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache     4083   4073  0 20:38 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

the i proceed doing `sudo chgrp apache ./assets` and then `sudo chmod g+w ./assets/` it all not working i guess this is a kind of server problem, any help on this will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe the directory owner has conflict with your php user,

run this command to get your apache user:

```
ps -ef | grep apache | grep -v grep
```

then you can see {apache_user}, run below command in your frontend/web directory:

```
sudo chgrp {apache_user} ./assets
sudo chmod g+w ./assets/
```

but if it doesn't work, give me about your operation system information

Comment: thanks for your help, i did as you say but it still doesn't workafter i run ps -ef | grep apache | grep -v grep what i got was the above output and i guess apache is my username i  run the sudo chgrp apache ./assets but still doesn't work, i run linux centos7

Comment: which one is your os? centos? ubonto?

Comment: i finally manage to get it work, i disable SElinux but i guess this isn't a good idea though but it fix the problem for me

Comment: So, I think your apache configuration has problem, but this will be work for now